# How to set switch case instead of if...else if.. in future double method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, switch-statement

```
  static Future<double> getMiningLeftHoursProgress(hours) async {
    double miningProgressValue = 0.0;

    String strDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

      double pendingHours = 24.0 - double.parse(strDigits(hours));

      if(pendingHours.isBetween(0.0, 2.4)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.1;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(2.4,4.8)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.2;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(4.8,7.2)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.3;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(7.2,9.6)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.4;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(9.6,12)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.5;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(12,14.4)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.6;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(14.4,16.8)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.7;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(16.8,19.2)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.8;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(19.2,21.6)){
        miningProgressValue = 0.9;
      }else if(pendingHours.isBetween(21.6,24)){
        miningProgressValue = 1.0;
      }

    return miningProgressValue;
  }
```

So above code is written in if else condition. but I want to set it in switch case. else I m not aware of switch case. let me know how to do It. also let me know which one is better ? if... else or switch ?

another thing is how do I reduce number of line for this code. as I'm just checking range between some specific value. and that value will be fixed (I mean it will start from 0.0 and end with 1.0 & also range is also incrementing by 2.4)

Comment: `miningProgressValue = (pendingHours / 2.4).ceil() * 0.1`

Comment: In your situation if else should be used because you cannot use range for dart switch case. Which one is better depends on situation.

Comment: Will you do anything else within the switch case conditions? Is that your function?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Range is not possible with `Dart` switch case for now.

You can go through this open issue in dart-lang - https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1660